# How to use cookies on angular 4+ to make get and post

Tags: angular, post, cookies, get

Can you provide an example or reference of how to use cookies on angular4+ performing GET and POST? On angularJS is documented but not on Angular.io. 
Any Equivalent to this: "//code.angularjs.org/X.Y.Z/angular-cookies.js" on Angular4+
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing something like follows:

```
 public postSomethingToServer(myUrl: string): Observable<any> {
    var body = `{"username":"ddd","password":"ddd"}`;
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });
    return this.http.post(myUrl, body, options)
      .map((response) => {

        return response.json(); 
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

To send the cookie in the request it was needed the (withCredentials: true) in the object passed to class RequestOptions.

For ASP Net Core apps if client and server are running on different servers needed to configure CORS

```
app.UseCors(config =>
                config.AllowAnyOrigin()                    
                      .AllowCredentials());
```

In case others face the same problem.

Comment: I think that AllowAnyOrigin() set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to * when compined this with withCredentials: true set in frontend call cause in my situation this exception: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using the new Angular 5 they introduced something called the `HttpInterceptor` (https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-all-requests-or-responses)

What you can do is create an interceptor that gets your cookie and handles it accordingly.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';

    function getCookie(name) {
     const splitCookie = cookie.split(';');
     for (let i = 0; i < splitCookie.length; i++) {
      const splitValue = val.split('=');
       if (splitValue[0] === name) {
         return splitValue[1];
       }
     }
     return '';
    }

    @Injectable()
    export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
      constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

      intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // Get the auth header from the service.
        const authHeader = getCookie('auth');
        // Clone the request to add the new header.
        const authReq = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', authHeader)});
        // Pass on the cloned request instead of the original request.
        return next.handle(authReq);
      }
    }
```

You can also use a library like this to handle cookies:
https://github.com/salemdar/ngx-cookie

Comment: Interceptors aren't exclusive to 5. They appeared in 4.3.